# ios:how to add google ads on back button of navigation item in swift?

Tags: ios, ads, uinavigationitem, interstitial

```
 let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "",
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
        target: nil,
        action: nil
    );
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

> i have use above code and i want to add google Interstitial ads in back button of navigation item.
>   my requirement is when i press back from second viewcontroller ads.
>    should would be come and when i close ads. first view controller
>    should open.

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved my problem by adding this below code in secondViewController. and its work perfectly.

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if (interstitial.isReady && showAd) {
        showAd = false
        print("iterstitalMain is ready")
        interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(parentViewController!)
        self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While creating back button, you should define selector/action methods for that backbutton.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "",
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(backButtonPressed)
)
```

in same controller you can have method which will execute after clicking back button

```
func backButtonPressed(){
   Print("Back Button Pressed")

   //Write code for showing google ads here.

}
```

Comment: i have added my above code is in viewdidload method of secndview controller. can i have to add anything in first view controller or not ?

Comment: Where do you have code for showing ads? Is it in SecondController or FirstViewController?

Comment: thats  i asking where i have to add code for ads.   in second controller or  first controller ?

Comment: You should add it in FirstViewControllers viewWillAppear method.

Comment: you said that i have to add advertise code in first controller so then above code is useless ?? because i added above mention code in secondview controller in viewDidLoad method.